# How can I change my bot's status from playing to listening?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to change my bot's status from playing to listening.

Here is my code:

```
client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`${client.user.username} ready!`);
  client.user.setActivity(`${PREFIX}help`);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
client.on("ready", () => {
  // This event will run if the bot starts, and logs in, successfully.
  console.log(`Bot has started, with ${client.users.cache.size} users, in ${client.channels.cache.size} channels of ${client.guilds.cache.size} guilds.`);
  // Example of changing the bot's playing game to something useful. `client.user` is what the
  // docs refer to as the "ClientUser".
  client.user.setActivity('<activity>', { type: 'LISTENING' });
});
```

This helped me out.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the activity using [`ClientUser.setActivity()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=setActivity):

```js
client.on("ready", () => { 
  console.log(`${client.user.username} ready!`); 
  client.user.setActivity({ type: 'LISTENING' });
});
```